# Character Check using java pattern?

Tags: java, design-patterns

i want to check the pattern like \ followed by \ or not . example:**\\patterone\\patterntwo**
i want to check whether **\\** pattern exist or not.please help me on this;

Comment: Can you use backticks \`\` to clarify the text your question?

Answer (score 1):

The question as originally asked doesn't make it clear whether you need to detect strings that contain a single backslash (`\`, spelled as `"\\"` in Java) or a doubled backslash (`\\`, spelled as `"\\\\"`).

To check whether a string contains a single `\`, look for the `'\\'` character using the `indexOf` string method:

```
if (myString.indexOF('\\') != -1) {
  // myString contains \
}
```

To check whether a string contains two backslashes, look for the `"\\\\"` substring instead:

```
if (myString.indexOF("\\\\") != -1) {
  // myString contains \\
}
```

In all cases, backslashes must be duplicated when writing literal strings because of their special meaning to the parser. Such doubled backslash characters represent a *single* backslash in the resulting string.